# Who does Faerie Fire affect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

As a level 1 druid, I have some questions about *Faerie Fire*.

1. Does it affect both enemies and allies? I mean, if both enemies and PCs
   are in the 20-foot cube area of effect, are they all outlined in
   light so that attack rolls against them have advantage?
2. If creatures that are already under the spell's effect leave the
   20-foot area do they stop being highlighted or not?
3. If creatures enter the 20-foot area after the spell starts and
   while it's still ongoing do they get outlined or not?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> **Faerie Fire (PHB 239)**
>   Any creature in the area when the spell is cast is also outlined in light if
>   it fails a Dexterity saving throw.

"Any creature" here includes hostile creatures, friendly creatures, and PCs. It even includes yourself if you cast it on an area that includes where you're standing.

"In the area when the spell is cast," read strictly, means that creatures who fail their saving throw and then leave the area *continue* to glow for the duration of the spell, and creatures who had been outside who proceed to step into the area *do not need to* make a saving throw, because they are not affected.

Comment: Think of it like a confetti bomb

Comment: To clarify. The spell says when the affected creatures fail /a/ dex saying throw (any dex save while the spell is cast). The spell itself does not provoke a saving throw though.